# Setting Route Data values on .net Core Web API controller within unit test

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, nunit, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to write unit tests for a Web API Controller in .net Core using NUnit.

I use the Route Data within one for the controller methods. So I'm trying to recreate this in my unit test.

So I want my setup method to look like this:

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    controller = new CustomersController();

    controller.RouteData = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteData();
    controller.RouteData.Values.Add("controller", "Customers");
}
```

The problem I have is RouteData is read-only.

How can I set this?

Comment: From the official documentation: "A controller unit test avoids scenarios such as filters, routing, and model binding. Tests that cover the interactions among components that collectively respond to a request are handled by integration tests"

Comment: Also says "Set up unit tests of controller actions to focus on the controller's behavior"

Comment: Thanks @NevilleNazerane. That is great but...

I can't test the behavior as I use a value in the route data as part of my one of my methods:  return CreatedAtRoute($"Get{RouteData.Values["controller"]}", ...);

This is in a base controller. As this fails I can't check the expected outcome. 

I guess I'll have to rework this.

Comment: According to the docs, if you are touching the docs, you would have to consider integration testing

Answer (score 0):

Use `new NoRouteData()` to pass empty route data for unit testing purpose